# (Python3.6 using cx_Freeze) Exe does not run pandas, numpy application

Tags: python-3.x, anaconda, spyder, cx-freeze

I wrote a .py script called Expiration_Report.py using the following libraries: pandas, numpy. This code runs perfectly fine when executed in Spyder(python 3.6).

(Using Anaconda for everything)

I then created another .py file called 'setup.py' with the following code in order to convert Expiration_Report.py to Expiration_Report.exe:

```
    import sys
    from cx_Freeze import setup, Executable

    # Dependencies are automatically detected, but it might need fine tuning.
      build_exe_options = {"packages": ["os"], 
                 "excludes": ["tkinter"]}

    # GUI applications require a different base on Windows (the default is for a
    # console application).
    base = None
    if sys.platform == "win32":
        base = "console" 


    setup(  name = "my prog",
        version = "1.0",
        description = "My application!",
        options = {"build_exe": build_exe_options},
        executables = [Executable("Expiration_Report.py", base = base)])
```

Then in the command prompt I write:

```
    python setup.py build
```

It builds without any errors. And the build folder is available with the .exe file as well. However, when I run the .exe file from the build folder: nothing happens.

Here is the code from the Expiration_Report.py script:

```
    import pandas as pd
    import numpy as np

    df = pd.read_excel('C:/Users/Salman/Desktop/WIP Board - 007.xlsx',                         index_col=None, na_values=['NA'])

    df.columns = df.iloc[12]
    df.columns

    df.shape

    df = df.dropna(axis=1, how = 'all')
    df

    df.columns

    df1 = df.copy()
    df1 = df1.iloc[13:]
    df1

    df1 = df1.dropna(axis=1, how = 'all')
    df1.shape

    from datetime import datetime
    print(str(datetime.now()))

    df2 = df1.copy()
    df2["Now_Time"] = pd.Series([datetime.now()] * (13+len(df1)))

    df2["Now_Time"]

    df2

    df2.fillna(value='NaN')

    df2 = df2.dropna(how='any')

    df2.shape

    df3 = df2.copy()
    df3 = df3[df3.Size>0]
    df3['Lot Expiration Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df3['Lot Expiration Date'])

    df3['Days_Countdown'] = df3[['Lot Expiration Date']].sub(df3['Now_Time'], axis = 0 )

    df3.dtypes

    df3['Hours_Countdown'] = df3['Days_Countdown'] / np.timedelta64(1, 'h')

    df3 = df3.sort_values('Hours_Countdown')

    df_expiration = df3[df3.Hours_Countdown<12]

    df_expiration['Hours_Countdown'].astype(int)
    df_expiration

    df_expiration.to_excel('C:/Users/Salman/Desktop/WIP Board - 000.xlsx', sheet_name = 'Sheet1')
```

The method for creating an exe file from cs_Freeze is correct. Because I converted a simple script HelloWorld.py to exe and it worked fine. It is not importing the pandas library and just exits the exe.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you need to add pandas and numpy to the packages list. cx_freeze can be a bit dodgy when it comes to finding all the necessary packages.

```
build_exe_options = {"packages": ["os", "numpy", "pandas"], 
             "excludes": ["tkinter"]}
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems that this (including the packages in the setu.py file) doesn'work for CX_freeze 5 and 6 ( as I understand it, these are the latest versions).
I had the same problem and whatever advice I followed here, including adding the packages. It is numpy that seems to cause the trouble.
You can test this by putting `import numpy` in your very simple  testscript, and see it crash when you freeze it.

The solution for me worked for python 3.4, but I doubt that it works under python 3.6:
I uninstalled cx_freeze and reinstalled cx_freeze 4.3.4 via `pip install cx_Freeze==4.3.4` and then it worked.

Answer (score 0):

`pd.read_csv` works but `pd.read_excel` does *not*, once the application is `cx_freezed`.

Pandas read_excel requires an import called `xlrd`. If you don't have it, you need to install it and `pd.read_excel` works after.

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). You can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/20908197)

Comment: Sorry - I forgot to edit it - I figured out a solution. I think the solution will help others who faced the same problem as me.